# C# FtpWebRequest.ClientCertificates is not implemented

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ftp

I'm getting a "Not Implemented" exception when trying to specify a certificate for my FTPWebRequest. Here is my code:

```
ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpURI);
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);

ftpRequest.EnableSsl = true;

X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certPath);
X509CertificateCollection certCollection = new X509CertificateCollection();
certCollection.Add(cert);
ftpRequest.ClientCertificates = certCollection;
```

Specifically, here's the error that is getting output from that last line:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.set_ClientCertificates (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection value) [0x00005] in <9f8c4786222746238eb929db40bf8dd1>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.FtpWebRequest.set_ClientCertificates(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection)
```

I've been able to connect to the FTP server using other programs, so I know the server is available at the specified URI with the specified credentials. I've also verified that the certificate is loading in, as I'm able to print out the info from it (and certCollection's Count is 1).

Not sure if relevant, but I am using Unity as a base. In my Unity settings I've specified .NET 4.x as my compatibility level. Does anyone have any insight into why this particular method is returning as not implemented? Is it maybe a Unity quirk, or am I using it wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: I've tried to run the program on a different machine on a different network and had the same results, so it's not an installation/config issue from what I can tell.

Comment: Try ftpRequest.ClientCertificates.Add() instead of ftpRequest.ClientCertificates = certCollection.

Comment: @ShahidSyed It returned the same exception for the get function as well: `System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.get_ClientCertificates () [0x00005] in <9f8c4786222746238eb929db40bf8dd1>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.FtpWebRequest.get_ClientCertificates()`

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306890/error-502-command-not-implemented-using-ftpwebresponse-net

Comment: @ShahidSyed That's completely unrelated. The other question is about an error coming from the server. The OP's code does not even gets to trying a connection.

Comment: @GReusch Do you get the same error with an empty collection? `ftpRequest.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It produced the same exception as the original, "FtpWebRequest.set_ClientCertificates not implemented", so it would seem it's not an issue with the cert collection object.

Comment: I my copy of .NET framework (4.7.2), the `FtpWebRequest.set_ClientCertificates` never throws `NotImplementedException`. All it does is `if (value == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (value));
        this.m_ClientCertificates = value;`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I see, it might be a Unity issue then since it's using 4.0.3 according to System.Enviornment.Version. Is there a way for me to check the implementation in my version of .NET?

Comment: I use [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) for that.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl An update, I opened my implementation using dotPeek and have confirmed that it is implemented in my version. The only thing that seemed unusual (and possibly incompatible with Unity) was the lock keyword in the getter, but the setter didn't have anything that should be causing issues. I packaged it up and sent it to the Unity devs to see if they can figure out if it's some quirk of their implementation of core .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

After following up with the Unity devs and filing a bug report, they got back to me confirming that it is an issue with the version of Mono being used in Unity 2019 and earlier.

They plan on updating their Mono version at some point in Unity 2020, which should fix the issue.